# Import Modules from same directory

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm

I'm trying to import python modules within the same directory using PyCharm which should be a very easy task. I've been struggling with this bug for a while and since I had to finish projects I regularly used the 'SourceFileLoader' from 'importlib.machinery' given the related base directory.
Since this method is quite inefficient for sharing my codes I'd like to finally deal with the problem for good.

Here one example:

Directory

C:\Users\Hallo.DESKTOP-4OVSO14\PycharmProjects\Uni\Tello_Video

contains files:

```
__init__.py
main.py
tello.py
tello_control_ui.py
```

main.py contains following code:

```
import tello from tello_control_ui 
import TelloUI


def main():

    drone = tello.Tello('', 8889)  
    vplayer = TelloUI(drone,"./img/")

    # start the Tkinter mainloop
    vplayer.root.mainloop() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which produces error message:

```
No module named 'tello'
```

If i change the import lines of this script to find the overall directory 'Tello_Video' it does the trick.

```
from Tello_Video import tello, tello_control_ui
```

Still this solution is very unconvenient since a lot of open source scripts are using the direct way for scripts in the same directory.

I'm running Python 3.7 on Windows 10 using Pycharm. I've read other question concerning this matter and already tried following methods:

1.) update package setuptools
2.) creating overall directory (in this example /Tello_Video) as 'Python Package'
3.) execute Pycharm in the same directory (/Tello_Video) where python files are stored
(4.) `__init__.py` is empty)

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: What is your root folder in Pycharm ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\bin\pycharm64.exe

Comment: Sorry, I meant in your project tree, what is the top folder ? Is it Tello_Video or Uni ?

Comment: The top folder is Uni

Comment: Seems like an issue with the naming of the modules. Try renaming tello.py into something else to remove the naming correlations between the objects and the module names.

Comment: This was just an example, I have this problem constantly. In addition, the object is called 'Tello' with capital T while the file is called 'tello'.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, your problem is that by making Uni your root project folder Pycharm is adding this path to the PYTHONPATH instead of the Tello_Video you would like. A solution is to use the mark your Tello_Video as source root (right click on folder > mark directory as > source). Another solution and maybe the best one is to use relative imports e.g. `import tello from tello_control_ui ` by `import .tello from tello_control_ui`. The stop before `tello` indicates that the file should be searched for in the same directory.

Comment: Hey Sylvavus, both ways are working. Thank you! Anyway, that still doesn't explain why it's not working the 'normal' way.